# React native _this2.context.function1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

react native **newbie** here.
I'm writing a program where I specify two functions:

- **addName**: assign as state a name
- **alertPopup**: shows the name inserted

These functions are in a ***App.js***. In ***page1.js*** I'm supposed to insert the value of the name using an Input text. Tho, when I press the button, it reports the error written in the title of this post.
*Where am I mistaking?*

App.js

```
...
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

      name:"",
    }
  }

  addName = (text) => {
        this.setState({ name: text })
     }

  alertPopup = (name) => {
    alert('The name inserted is: ' + name)
        }
...
```

page1.js

```
  <TextInput
     ...
     onChangeText = {this.context.addName}
   />
     ...
   <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.context.alertPopup(this.context.name)} style={styles.loginBtn}>
         <Text style={styles.loginText}> See The name </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Comment: function1 of the title should be instead alertPopup

Comment: Have you tried something like `console.log(this.context)` in `componentDidMount` to make sure the context is implemented correctly?